# Activar/desactivar checkbox bootstrap-toogle

Tags: php, bootstrap

Tengo varios lineas de detalle en pantalla, cada una con dos checkbox (uno de ellos bootstrap-toogle) y quisiera que cuando el primer checkbox se active, se enable el segundo y se ponga en on, y cuando se desactive el primer checkbox, se ponga en disable y en off (siempre el de la misma linea).

Codigo del primer checkbox:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox_class' name='baja[]' value='' id='check1' onclick='validar_sino(this);''></td>";
```

Codigo del segundo checkbox:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' disabled name='sino' id='sino' data-toggle='toggle' data-size='mini' data-on='Si' data-off='No' data-onstyle='success' data-offstyle='danger'></td>";
```

Codigo javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function validar_sino(elemento) { 
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("check1"); 
    if (checkbox1.checked == true) { 
        $('#sino').bootstrapToggle('on');           
        $('#sino').bootstrapToggle('enable'); 
    } else { 
        $('#sino').bootstrapToggle('off');         
        $('#sino').bootstrapToggle('disable'); 
    } 
} 
</script>
```

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo en tu código al parecer usas jQuery, por lo cual propongo una solución con dicho framework:

Consiste en detectar cuando cambia un elemento con la clase `checkbox class` y que esté contenido en un `<td>`, a continuación buscamos los siguientes `<td>` (teniendo en cuenta que no conocemos la totalidad de tu código y no sé si hayan más td entre los dos que nos importan), posteriormente encontramos sus elementos "checkbox" contenidos en dichos td y activamos/desactivamos según el nuevo estado de nuestro primer checkbox:

```js
$('td .checkbox_class').change(function() {
  var nextCheckbox = $(this).parent().nextAll('td').children('[type=checkbox]');
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    nextCheckbox.prop('disabled', false);      
  } else {
    nextCheckbox.prop('disabled', true).prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox_class' name='baja[]' value='' id='check1'/></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' disabled name='sino' id='sino' data-toggle='toggle' data-size='mini' data-on='Si' data-off='No' data-onstyle='success' data-offstyle='danger'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox_class' name='baja2[]' value='' id='check2'/></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' disabled name='sino2' id='sino2' data-toggle='toggle' data-size='mini' data-on='Si' data-off='No' data-onstyle='success' data-offstyle='danger'></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```